# Bounds for the distance between nested balls.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a  <s>metric space</s>  vector space, $d$ a metric and $a \in X$. For the balls with radius $0<r_{1}<r_{2}$, $B_{r_{1}}(a)$ and $B_{r_{2}}(a)$ I'd like to show that $d(B_{r_{1}}(a),y):=\inf_{x \in B_{r_{1}}(a)}d(x,y)\leq r_{2}-r_{1}$ for all $y \in B_{r_{2}}$.

My first attempt uses the triangular inequality but the bound is too large:
$$d(B_{r_{1}}(a),y):=\inf_{x \in B_{r_{1}}(a)}d(x,y) \leq \inf_{x \in B_{r_{1}}(a)}d(x,z)+d(z,y)=r_{2}$$
The last equal sign follows since $d(x,z)=0$ for $z=x$.

**Update**
I think I found a proof.
$$d(B_{r_{1}}(a),y)
=
\inf_{x \in B_{r_{1}}(a)}d(x,y)
\leq
\inf_{x \in B_{r_{1}}(a) \cap  B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)} d(x,y)
=r_{2}-r_{1}
$$
Since $d(x,y)\leq r_{2}-r_{1}$ for all $x \in  B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)$.
However this requires that $B_{r_{1}}(a) \cap  B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)$ is not empty. I've tried to prove this by contradiction but couldn't finish the proof.

Claim:  $B_{r_{1}}(a) \cap  B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)\neq \emptyset$

Assume $B_{r_{1}}(a) \cap  B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y) = \emptyset$. Then $d(a,x)>r_{1}$ for all $x \in B_{r_{2}-r_{1}}(y)$. I was hoping to show something like this
$$d(a,y)\geq |d(a,x)-d(x,y)|>r_{2}$$.

Comment: Why are you trying to prove this statement?  It is not true in general.

Comment: Isn't it? But I think at least in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ this should be true.

Comment: With $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ I would simply pick a point from the intersection of a line between $a$ and $y$ and the boundary of $B_{r_{1}}(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general.  For instance, if $X=\{0,1\}$, then $B_{1/2}(0)=\{0\}$ so $d(B_{1/2}(0),1)=1$ but $1\in B_{1+\epsilon}(0)$ for any $\epsilon>0$ and $1>(1+\epsilon)-1/2$ for small $\epsilon$.

It is not true even if you require that for any $r\geq 0$ and any $x\in X$ there exists $y$ such that $d(x,y)=r$.  For instance, take $X=\{0\}\times(-\infty,0]\cup\{1\}\times[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then $d(B_{1/2}(0,0),(1,0))=1$ even though $d((0,0),(1,0))=1$, since no point of $B_{1/2}(0,0)$ is closer to $(1,0)$ than $(0,0)$ itself.

Comment: I see. I think $X$ needs to be a vector space instead of only a metric space.